# MSI Radeon R9 270 Graphics drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, msi

How am i supposed to download these drivers and utilities? I am a complete newb to linux, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Note: The drivers and utilities are windows based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

fglrx-updates is the updated version of the proprietary video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators. Reboot the computer to enable the graphics driver.

Optionally you can also install the Catalyst Control Center (Linux Edition) for the AMD graphics accelerators. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-amdcccle
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try that, but what about the drivers and utilities that come from the Disc that is included with the card? (Ex. Msi afterburner...) thanks again!

Comment: I added this information to my answer. Catalyst Control Center is a graphical application that has some but not all of the utilities from the installation CD that came with the graphics card.

Comment: Thanks, so I'm guessing theres no way to get the utilities from the cd? Sorry for asking so many questions, just worried that I might need to spend $119 on windows just for a utilities that I would rather have

Comment: Instead of MSI Afterburner you could try rovclock - utility to control frequency rates of your Radeon card - from the Ubuntu Software Center. I have used fglrx-updates and fglrx-amdcccle myself and they work just fine, however I have never tried rovclock. rovclock apparently stands for "Radeon overclock".