# How to know if graphics card is supported on Unity?

Tags: graphics

I am looking to purchase a computer and put Ubuntu / Unity on it.  I am not a hardware expert but I do know how to navigate around Ubuntu.  I am having trouble finding whether or not the computers graphic card is supported or not.  I am not looking to maximize the use of the graphics card but want to make sure it will support external monitors (hopefully 2).  here are the specifications on the computer:

```
Inspiron 15 7000 Series
16GB, DDR3L, 2 DIMM, 1600MHz
256GB Solid State Drive
**AMD Radeon R7 M270 4GB DDR3**
15.6-inch 4K Ultra HD (3840 x 2160) Truelife LED-Backlit Touch Display with Wide Viewing Angle (IPS)
802.11ac + Bluetooth 4.0, Dual Band 2.4&5GHz, 2x2
MUI Documentation
Backlit Keyboard, US English
US Power Cord
BRAD15BDW1601_5208/US/CA/BTO
58WHr, 4-C (rem) [58 WHr, 4-Cell Battery (removable)]
802.11ac + Bluetooth 4.0, Dual Band 2.4&5GHz, 2x2 Wireless Driver
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT
Here is the link to the computer:
http://configure.us.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?oc=cai157w8ps5208&model_id=inspiron-15-7548-laptop&c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04

Comment: Here is the actual model of the computer:  http://configure.us.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?oc=cai157w8ps5208&model_id=inspiron-15-7548-laptop&c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04

Comment: Run a LiveCD or LiveUSB and test - that's the only true way to test if the graphics card will work.

Comment: I checked here http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about hardware recommendation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSI Radeon R9 270 Graphics drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/496713/msi-radeon-r9-270-graphics-drivers)

Comment: Did you ever try run a liveCD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this Romanian [Website](http://www.evomag.ro/PORTABILE-Laptopuri/Dell-Laptop-Dell-Inspiron-15-5548-Procesor-Intel-Core-i7-5500U-4M-Cache-up-to-3.00-GHz-Broadwell-15.6-8GB-1TB-8GB-SSHD-AMD-Radeon-R7-M270-4GB-USB-3.0-HDMI-Ubuntu-3-Ani-Garantie-942874.html), you should be good!

**EDIT:** Model number on the laptop itself is slightly different, but the graphics card is the same model so laptop model shouldn't make any difference.

**EDIT 2:** So, it was clarified that this is a certified (pre-installed) rather than a certified installation, meaning there could have been modifications done the standard Ubuntu image, such as custom drivers. So, you *should* be okay, but as the comments on the original question indicated, it would be best to try with a **LiveUSB** first because one of those modifications could have been a custom driver for the graphics.

Comment: No, it's different, this is a pre-installed version of Ubuntu, which means that it uses a customized Ubuntu ISO image that was provided to the OEM, for more information please refer to this [FAQ](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+faq/2219).

Comment: Ah, so they could have used drivers they made themselves. I see. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to check this link ?

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware

Sorry for my fast answer.

In your case your `AMD Radeon R7 M270 4GB DDR3` (`AMD Radeon™ R9 270 Series` ? or `AMD Radeon™ R7 260 Series` ?) seems to be supported (see release note on the driver).

### Linux Distributions Supported:

The latest version of the ATI Catalyst™ Linux Software Suite is designed to support the following Linux distributions:

Linux Distribution Specific
    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Suite 7.0 , 6.5
    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, 14.04 LTS

source : http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalystOmegaLINReleaseNotes.aspx

I can't tell you it will works @ 100%, but all seems good (or will be fixed quite fast, because it's new).

The real problem it's when you have an old graphics card :)